# TextInputLayout - Hint padding issue

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I am using textInputLayout in my application, but I am getting additional padding to the Hint. Can anyone help me out.

Screenshot:
[image]

Xml Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:id="@+id/outlined_member_name_text_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/select_contact_button">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/member_name_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|text" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Your code as is do not have extra padding in hint (Tested your xml). You can test it by creating new project and copy pasting the same xml. Negative padding seems a hacky solution. i suggest you take a look at your styles see if you don't have anything which is causing this behavior in TextInputLayout and also Check if you have the latest material library.

Comment: Your Code Properly works in my Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add -ve padding to TextInputEditText, it should solve the extra padding issue that you have. For example  I have used -10dp you can check what fits your case.

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout       
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/outlined_member_name_text_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/select_contact_button">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/member_name_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="-10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```